# Django not reconnecting to database?

Tags: django, psycopg2, django-channels

I am using Django channels and once the database connection gets closed, it keeps on returning the following error for subsequent events in consumer:

```
Exception inside application: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

My question is that why is Django not trying to reconnect to database server automatically. If I have to handle it, where should I handle it?

Should I wrap the try except around the whole code and reconnect whenever this error occur.

I am using pgbouncer layer in between and my database config looks like:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'NAME': 'db_pgbouncer',
'USER': '<user_name>',
'PASSWORD': '<password>',
'HOST': '<ip>',
'PORT': '6432',
'CONN_MAX_AGE': None
```

**Edit 1:**

Traceback

```
File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1097, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 396, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/server/proj/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Comment: How does the connection get closed?

Comment: My pgbouncer machine got restarted, due to some failure

Comment: @IainShelvington i have edited the question and basically it is affecting the code where i have used atomic block.

Comment: This issue seems to recommend dropping `CONN_MAX_AGE` from your database settings https://github.com/django/channels/issues/871

Comment: try removing 'CONN_MAX_AGE': None from settings and i believe it will work fine.

Comment: But then it will close the connections after every request and making a new connection is expensive

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an async consumer? If so, make sure you wrap all database calls within any async context using `database_sync_to_async`. DB connections within this context will be cleaned up. See docs [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html#database-sync-to-async) for example code